# Change color of one value in the x-axis charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I build a stacked bar chart in Charts.js.
I want that my x-axis will have 2 colors:
Ona color for the value in my x-axis that has the highest bar and another color for the rest of the values.
For example - [image: here] I want that the value "do nothing" will be in a different color.
This is how I build my chart:

```
 const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: data.xs_action,
            datasets: [{
                    label: ['Head_1= Right Lane'],
                    data: data.ys_H1a,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', ],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)', ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                },

                {
                    label: ['Head_2 = High Speed'],
                    data: data.ys_H2a,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', ],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                },

                {
                    label: ['Head_3 = Change Lane'],
                    data: data.ys_H3a,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', ],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)', ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    stack: 'Stack 0',
                },

            ]

        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                    },

                    ticks: {
                        color: 'blue',
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                }
            }
        }

    });

}
```

In my data, I also have the position of the x-value I want to appear in a different color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scriptable option for the tick color for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [{
        label: ['Head_1= Right Lane'],
        data: [10, 5, 6],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', ],
        borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)', ],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },

      {
        label: ['Head_2 = High Speed'],
        data: [2, 6, 5],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', ],
        borderColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', ],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },

      {
        label: ['Head_3 = Change Lane'],
        data: [10, 3, 4],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', ],
        borderColor: ['rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)', ],
        borderWidth: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          color: (ctx) => {
            const maxValues = ctx.chart.data.datasets.reduce((acc, curr) => {
              curr.data.forEach((e, i) => {
                if (acc[i]) {
                  acc[i] = acc[i] + e;
                } else {
                  acc[i] = e;
                }
              });
              return acc;
            }, {});

            const labelIndex = ctx.chart.data.labels.indexOf(ctx.tick.label);

            return maxValues[labelIndex] === Math.max(...Object.values(maxValues)) ? 'blue' : 'red'
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

On a side note, namespace for the grid has been changed in V3 from `gridLines` to `grid` thats why your gridlines are not hidden.